# Ошибка после установки Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, install, asus

На ноуте **ASUS F540S** был 10 виндовс. В один момент он перестал загружаться. (Когда и как не знаю, ноут не мой) Лично мне загрузить не удалось.
При установке Win7 с флешки проблем не было. Но при загрузке за секунду проскочил BSOD и ноут перезагрузился. После этого вылез экран с параметрами загрузки системы. И все по кругу.

Пробовал раза 3. Все то же.

Системный раздел удалял. После второй неудачи — удалил первый раздел (500 Мб) Остальные разделы не могу, есть нужная информация.

В БИОСе SATA Mode только AHCI, пункт активен, только других вариантов выбора нет.

Comment: memtest и тест диска прогоните...

Comment: Ни виктория ни mhdd винта не видит

Comment: Может где-то тут и проблема?